# Data from variables lost using a registry class and WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I have the following Registry class (I called it Storage) in my MVC:

```
class Storage {

    public static $vars = array();

    public static function set($key, $value = null) {
        self::$vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        return isset(self::$vars[$key]) ? self::$vars[$key] : null;
    }

}
```

I also have a **Router.php**, where I set a variable for Registry like this:

```
Storage::set('arg', 'this is my argument');
```

Now I want to access my variable in a controller. I'm accessing it as following:

```
$test = Storage::get('arg');
```

But the whole array from Storage is completely empty, and it returns null. I tried catching the array in **set** function, it sets up the array, but in **get** it's empty again. I'm using WAMP, and I have a feeling that could be a problem, unless it's somewhere else. Any ideas?

Comment: Setting the data and then reading the data all has to be part of a single execution. If you are expecting this data to presist between lets say 2 pages it wont even though you made it static.

Comment: it's not two pages, just two separate controllers. Is there any way to make it persistent?